# JavaScript snippet not working in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

So in Chrome and Firefox this works:

```
<output for="priceSlider" id="priceLevel">$350</output>
<script>
function output(prc) {
    document.querySelector('#priceLevel').value = "$"+prc/100;
}
</script>
```

It changes the price as the slider is moved and also changes it to the way I want it to look. In Edge/IE it doesn't do anything. Is there something I need to change for Edge/IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<output>` tags are not supported in IE.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output

Comment: The `output` element is presently [under consideration](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/outputelement?filter=f3f0000bf&search=output).